# Spinner item not showing as dropdown but in the top of the spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

i am using spinner in my code which i had declare in my xml

xml code for spinner:-

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

so as can be seen that the spinner is down the one button which is also in that layout xml .Now when i run my app its loading all data correctly but the item is showing in the top of the spinner not in the down side of the spinner.Mentioning the screenshot how it appear

[image: Spinner when placed down of the button]

but when i m using the same spinner parallel to the button the spinner dropdown effect working very fine.Here is the screenshot how it appear.

[image: Spinner when placed parallel to the button]

so can any tell me how can we solve this kind of scenario.thanks for any reply.

Comment: based on the space available in the Screen, Spinner will decide to show the popup on top or bottom...

Comment: There is no available space for the spinner at the bottom side that's why it is coming on top..

Answer (score 2):

try this hope this will help you

```
 android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```