# Why my Spinner Displays list upside instead of downSide in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I have used 2 spinners in my android activity,one is for country and other is for states,country spinner displays data as dropDown List(down side),But the state spinner gives me data enlisted to upside as shown in image.I want to display it same as country spinner(down side),Please help me.my spinner code is as below:
**code**

```
 <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spr_country"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_cntry_id"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spr_states"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spr_country"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

[image: Upside spinner]

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't have space.

Comment: @Aniruddha- is there any way to display it forcefully ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spinner does not have Sufficient space to display spinner popup to downside. Android system will automatically popup it to upside.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277102/spinner-item-not-showing-as-dropdown-but-in-the-top-of-the-spinner